# Which Forces do we consider while calculating Torque?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, torque, rotation

In the following question, will we consider the weight of the two spheres while calculating torque acting on the body? When I tried to do the calculation of torque while considering the torque provided by the weight of the two spheres, the m/M was coming out negative. [image]Can someone please provide an insight as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It is recommended that you type out the essential text out of the image, and just keep the diagram in image form, this helps others to refer it easily and it will make look less like asking to solve a Homework/Exercise Question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider *all forces acting on the pipe* and equipollent moments per the free body diagram you have.

[image: fbd]

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the sketch provided by JAlex, with no friction, the spheres exert no vertical forces on the cylinder.  There are two torques acting on the spheres relative to the center of the lower sphere, one from gravity and the other from the normal force from the right hand wall (both acting on the upper sphere: mg(2r cos(θ)) – N(2r sin(θ)) = 0, where  θ is the angle  between the line joing the centers of the spheres and the horizontal.  This can be solved for, N , which must be the same on both sides.  At the critical condition (when the cylinder is ready to tip), all the weight of the cylinder is supported by the (green) vector force at the lower right side. Then there are three torques acting on the cylinder relative to the lower right edge; two from the normal forces from the spheres, and one from the weight of the cylinder:  N(r + 2r sin(θ)) – Nr – Mg(R/2) = 0.   Finally: r cos(θ) + r = R.  Combine these three equations to get, m/M, in terms of, R, and, r.